# I want to use turborepo in a project where I don't use next.js. Is something like this possible?

Tags: next.js, vercel, turborepo

I searched a bit but couldn't find the exact solution.

How to use turborepo without using next.js any comments about it guys?

I don't want to use next.js because its advantages are not important to me but I really like turborepo. There is a solution built with next.js in vercel's documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next.js is in no way a pre-condition to use Truborepo. You can use Turborepo within any JS code base that you‘d like.

All you have to do is to create an app, for example with Vue.js, in the /apps directory. Once that‘s done, be sure to [register the needed pipelines](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/core-concepts/monorepos/running-tasks#defining-a-pipeline) in your Turborepo config-file (turbo.json). And that‘s basically it.

[Here](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/migrating-to-a-monorepo) is a more thorough explanation of what I tried to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy just follow the instruction here if you want to create a vite app
Run the command where you want to create your app within turborepo, generally at the root of apps directory

Step 1.

```
pnpm create vite
```

Step 2.
Name the app in the prompt, this will create a directory and select the template you want to create your app with.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project

Answer (score 0):

Vercel have few offical monorepo `Turborepo` templates that you can access by just modifying `npx create-turbo@latest` cli commands.

For example you don't want default `NextJs` app starter app instead you want `Svelte`. You just add a `svelet` flag in the installation command. It will create a starter app with `svelte` and do all required configuration.

```
npx create-turbo@latest -e with-svelte
```

You can find all official templates made by `vercel` over on their [official website](https://vercel.com/templates/monorepos) ⭐.